# Define and deduce the parameter from Template template parameter

Tags: c++

Based on the example on [pp. 179](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600298X)

```
template<template<typename T, typename A> class C, typename T, typename A>
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
void erase(C<T, A>&c, const T& item)
{
    c.erase(std::remove(c.begin(), c.end(), item), c.end());
}

int _tmain(int /*argc*/, _TCHAR* /*argv*/[])
{
    list<int> lst;
    lst.push_back(42);
    erase(lst, 42);
}
```

If I remove the `typename T, typename A` from the `erase` function signature, the VS2010 compiler gives the following errors:

> ```
> Error 1   error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier
> Error 2   error C2065: 'A' : undeclared identifier
> Error 3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> Error 4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
> ```

**Question1**> What is the reason behind these compilation errors.

Is it true that we always have to explicitly define the type parameters used in the template template parameter?

**Question2**> When we call the following line, how does compiler deduce the type of `A`?

```
erase(lst, 42)
```

Is it true that the compiler deduce the type `A` based on the default argument for template parameter A that is defined in `list`?

Refer to [list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/)

```
template < class T, class Allocator = allocator<T> > class list;
```

And the type `A` is `allocator<T>`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Question 1**

First `T` and `A` are parameters to `C`, not to your `erase()` template.  Therefore, they are not visible to it, what is visible are the second and third parameters you highlight with ^^^.  Note that the first parameter is *not* a typename/class, it is a class template.  A class template itself is not a type, only its instantiations are.

To better understand how first `T` and `A` are not visible and in fact don't play any role, you can rewrite it like this:

```
template<template<typename, typename> class C, typename T, typename A>
```

**Question 2**

It can deduce `A` because `lst` as passed as `C<T, A>`, so `A` is the second parameter of `lst` type's class template.

Finally, you should rewrite your function template in a different way:

```
template <typename C>
void erase(C& c, const typename C::value_type& item)
{
    c.erase(std::remove(c.begin(), c.end(), item), c.end());
}
```

This way, you don't restrict number and meaning of `C` template parameters.  In fact, here `C` can be a non-templated type if wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove these, A and T are only known in the context of C and not in the context of your erase() template.